# Terraform cannot attach created integrations into routes for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use Terraform to deploy API Gateway that routes traffic into my domain `google.com` as an example.

I use [aws_apigatewayv2_api](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_api) for creating HTTP_PROXY type for integrations. I went through the docs but still cannot find the way to attach an integration into a route `GET /sitemap.xml`. How to deal with this?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "_" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api._.id
  stage_name  = ""

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "_" {
  name          = "example"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "apigateway_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  route_key = "GET /sitemap.xml"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "apigateway_intergration" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY"

  connection_type      = "INTERNET"
  description          = "Gateway intergration for EC2"
  integration_method   = "ANY"
  integration_uri      = "https://www.google.com"
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
}

# resource "aws_apigatewayv2_deployment" "apigateway_deployment" {
#   api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_route.apigateway_route.api_id
#   description = "Example deployment"

#   lifecycle {
#     create_before_destroy = true
#   }
# }

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "apigateway_stage" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  name   = "example-stage"
}
```

[image: UI API Gateway integration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing several components. Most importantly there is **no link between** your `aws_apigatewayv2_route` and `aws_apigatewayv2_integration`.

The link is established using [target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_route#target) argument.

Similarly, there is no link between `aws_apigatewayv2_stage` and `aws_apigatewayv2_deployment`.

You can have a look at the following version of the code:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_deployment" "example" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  description = "Example deployment"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  
  depends_on = [
    aws_apigatewayv2_route.apigateway_route
  ]
}


resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "_" {
  name          = "example"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "apigateway_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  route_key = "GET /sitemap.xml"
  
  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.apigateway_intergration.id}"
  
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "apigateway_intergration" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY"

  connection_type      = "INTERNET"
  description          = "Gateway intergration for EC2"
  integration_method   = "ANY"
  integration_uri      = "https://www.google.com"
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "apigateway_stage" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api._.id
  name   = "example-stage"
  deployment_id = aws_apigatewayv2_deployment.example.id  
}
```

The above code **correctly** creates integration:

[image]